# how to guarantee data avaliability between different block of shared memory

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, shared-memory

I used mmap to map files for data sharing bewteen processes, I then used another shared memory to notify the process when data is ready. a semaphore is created inside the shared memory.

after data is written into all the files, I immediately used the semaphore to notify the data is ready.

is it possible that the data in some files is not available to the reader process after it received the notification?

below is a sample code that tries to mimic the case, it seems that the data is always available to reader once the notification is received.but I am not sure if it's just because I didn't run it long enough. (some of my co-works claim that they run into the issue occasionally that data is not updated when they are using the similar pattern in the sample code)

is there any theory or official document that can prove that the code below is ok or not?

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_condition.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <optional>
#include <fstream>
#include <ios>
#include <thread>
// data to notify if update is done
template <class T> struct SharedData {
    SharedData(const T &init_value) : data_(init_value) {}
    // Mutex to protect access to the data
    boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex mutex_;
    // Condition to wait before the data is set
    boost::interprocess::interprocess_condition cond_;
    T data_;
};

template <class T> class SharedDataWriter {
public:
    SharedDataWriter(const std::string& name, const T &init_value)
    : shm_(boost::interprocess::open_or_create, name.data(), boost::interprocess::read_write)
    , name_(name) {
        shm_.truncate(sizeof(SharedData<T>));
        region_.emplace(shm_, boost::interprocess::read_write);
        void *addr = region_->get_address();
        shared_data_ = new (addr) SharedData<T>(init_value);
    }
    ~SharedDataWriter() {
        boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove(name_.data());
    }

    void set_value(const T& value) {
        boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex> lock(shared_data_->mutex_);
        shared_data_->data_ = value;
        shared_data_->cond_.notify_all();
    }
private:
    boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object shm_;
    std::optional<boost::interprocess::mapped_region> region_;
    std::string name_;
    SharedData<T>* shared_data_ = nullptr;
};

template <class T> class SharedDataReader {
public:
    SharedDataReader(const std::string& name)
    : shm_(boost::interprocess::open_only, name.data(), boost::interprocess::read_write)
    , region_(shm_, boost::interprocess::read_write) {
        void * addr = region_.get_address();
        shared_data_ = (SharedData<T> *)addr;
    }

    T wait_value() {
        boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex> lock(
            shared_data_->mutex_);
        shared_data_->cond_.wait(lock);
        return shared_data_->data_;
    }
private:
    boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object shm_;
    boost::interprocess::mapped_region region_;
    SharedData<T> *shared_data_ = nullptr;
};
// file content is basically a table
struct FixedHeader {
    int32_t col_size_;
    int32_t row_size_;

    void * get_value_start_addr(char * begin) {
        return begin + sizeof(FixedHeader);
    }
};

struct SingleMappedFile {
    SingleMappedFile(const std::string& filename)
    : mapped_file_(filename.data(), boost::interprocess::read_write)
    , region_(mapped_file_, boost::interprocess::read_write) {}
    FixedHeader& get_header() {
        return *((FixedHeader*)get_start_addr());
    }
    void write(int32_t row_index, int32_t value) {
        int32_t * value_start = (int32_t *)get_value_start_addr();
        for (int32_t i = 0; i < get_header().col_size_; ++i) {
            value_start[row_index * get_header().col_size_ + i] = value;
        }
    }
    int32_t* get_row(int32_t row_index) {
        int32_t * value_start = (int32_t *)get_value_start_addr();
        return value_start + row_index * get_header().col_size_;
    }
    void * get_start_addr() const { return region_.get_address(); }
    const char * get_file_name() const { return mapped_file_.get_name(); }
private:
    char * get_value_start_addr() {
        return (char*)get_header().get_value_start_addr((char*)get_start_addr());
    }
    boost::interprocess::file_mapping mapped_file_;
    boost::interprocess::mapped_region region_;
};

void writer_main() {
    // create 50 files and set init value
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        std::ofstream file(std::string("file_") + std::to_string(i), std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
        int32_t col = 5000;
        int32_t row = 300;
        file.write((char*)&col, sizeof(col));
        file.write((char*)&row, sizeof(row));
        for (int32_t k = 0; k < col * row; ++k) file.write((char*)&k, sizeof(k));
    }

    // mmap all these 50 files
    std::vector<SingleMappedFile> mapped_files;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        mapped_files.emplace_back(std::string("file_") + std::to_string(i));
    }

    SharedDataWriter<int32_t> writer("notify", -1);

    int32_t value = 1;
    int32_t row_index = 0;
    while(true) {
        char c;
        std::cout << "input anything to write data." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> c;
        // write data into mapped files and notify
        for (auto& mfile : mapped_files) {
            mfile.write(row_index, value);
        }
        writer.set_value(row_index);
        row_index++;
    }
}

void thread_func(SharedDataReader<int32_t>& reader, SingleMappedFile& mfile) {
    // wait for notification and check if data is updated
    while (true) {
        int32_t row_index = reader.wait_value();
        int32_t* row = mfile.get_row(row_index);
        for (int32_t i = mfile.get_header().col_size_; i > 0; --i) {
            if (row[i - 1] != 1) {
                throw std::runtime_error("data not updated.");
            }
        }
        std::cout << "row_index = " << row_index << std::endl;
    }
}

void reader_main() {
    std::vector<SingleMappedFile> mapped_files;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        mapped_files.emplace_back(std::string("file_") + std::to_string(i));
    }
    SharedDataReader<int32_t> reader("notify");
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    // create 50 threads, each check one file.
    for (auto& mfile : mapped_files) {
        threads.emplace_back([&reader, &mfile]() { thread_func(reader, mfile); });
    }
    for (auto& t : threads) t.join();
}

int main(int argc, char **) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        reader_main();
    } else {
        writer_main();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mre]of your code.

Comment: @stark I post a sample code, but it actually runs ok. but I don't know if it's ok just because I didn't run it long enough. can you take a look at the code, and see if it's ok in theory? or there is a flaw in theory? thanks